# OpenLayers WMS feature styling

Tags: openlayers, wms, style

I add WMS connection to openLayers, it has 127 different layers. I add one Layer which occurred to be small icons symbolizing Pictures on map. But the styling is ugly, according to the specification  of layers (GetCapabilities) "Styles" is set to "Default". I want to style each icon on this WMS layer, but i cant understand how.

My sample code below:

```
new TileLayer({
    id             : 5,
    name           : 'test picture_1',
    visible : false,
    source  : new TileWMS({
        url     : WMSUrl,
        params  : {
            'TILED'     : true,
            'LAYERS'    : 118
        },
        transparent: 'true',
        projection : "EPSG:3057"
    }),
}),
```

How could i style all features (which are small icons on the map) in this layer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, a WMS returns a picture of the map that has been rendered by the WMS server. If you want to style a layer in the client you have two choices:

1. request the actual data from a WFS server and style it yourself.
2. Send a SLD file to the WMS server for it to use to style the data. You can check for this option by looking for a line like:
   `<UserDefinedSymbolization SupportSLD="1" UserLayer="1" UserStyle="1" RemoteWFS="1"/>` in the getcapabilities response, you need UserStyle to not equal 0.

In both cases this will only work if the server in question supports that functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now i will try to find out solution with WFS layers and receive them as JSON objects in order to set styles for icon. But, by the way, how could i know if  this WMS  service supports SLD file ? And Where to know how to structure SLD ?

Comment: Thanks for the full answer! it really takes me time to understand all WMS possibilities, now it's clear.

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem